# Does $y'=f(y), y(0)=0$ have a continuous differentiable solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does $y'=f(y), y(0)=0$ have a continuous differentiable solution , Where

$$ f(y)=\cases{
0 & if $y>0$\\ 
1 & if $y\leq 0$
}$$

[image]
 how to solve this problem is we can apply picard theorem..can any help me with this

Comment: $y$ can clearly not reach any number above $0$, but how can it keep having derivative $1$ then? I think you should rather have $\geq$ on the top line and $<$ on the second line.

Comment: @Arthur..no  its right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course Picard's theorem does not apply, but there might exist an acceptable solution nevertheless.

The given IVP has a bona fide solution $y(x)=x$, valid for $x\leq0$. But there is indeed no solution valid in a full neighborhood of $x=0$.

*Proof.* A prospective solution in an interval $\>]{-h},,h[\>$ has $y'(0)=1$, hence satisfies
$$y(x)=x+o(x)=x\bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)\qquad(x\to0)\ .$$
In particular we have $y(x)>0$ for $0<x<\delta$ and therefore $y'(x)=0$ for $0<x<\delta$. Now it is a theorem that the derivative of a differentiable function automatically satisfies the intermediate value theorem, whereas the derivative of the function $x\mapsto y(x)$ envisaged here assumes only the values $0$ and $1$.$\quad\square$